# Referencing another layer in Field Calculator inside Graphical Modeler

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-modeler

I want to use the Field Calculator inside the Graphical Modeler to create a new column in an input vector layer (`LAYER1`) using data in another layer (`LAYER2`). `LAYER2` is the output of another algorithm inside the model.

The formula is as follows:

`attribute(get_feature("LAYER2", 'WKT', geom_to_wkt(start_point($geometry))) , 'NODEID')`

Actually, I am trying to implement an algorithm similar to what's described in [Getting points-touching-a-line attributes back to lines layer using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208883/getting-points-touching-a-line-attributes-back-to-lines-layer-using-qgis/209315).

When used outside the model, it works perfectly.

When used inside the model, the column is always created with NULL values.

Any ideas on how to reference `LAYER2` inside the Field Calculator for this to work?

Comment: Hit the same problem. Tried using the saved name of the layer, the one presented in the GUI ("X from algorithm Y"), but neither are found. The dependencies are set up properly. Log shows temporary names only — any way to catch those?

Comment: What about a join? Field Calculator always works on only one single layer.

Comment: Maybe there's a way to save the desired 'WKT' value from "LAYER2" as a variable within the model. Then you could use that variable in the Field Calculator instead of your `attribute(get_feature())` formula.

Comment: @Stefan_Fairphone It can work on multiple, that's why the functions. The problem is just in the modeller context. If you have a concrete idea with a join, please provide an answer.

Comment: You would need a key attribute that is the same for a feature in both layers. Do you have such a key attribute (some kind of ID, etc.)?

Comment: They do share one, yes. It's a workaround, but better than nothing.

Comment: Could you please zip those two layers and upload it? It's just to see your attributes and work directly with them.

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx - Probably won't make a difference but have you tried using single quotes around `"LAYER2"` instead of double?

Comment: I don't remember, but it shouldn't matter — the expression works when used manually in the field calculator. @CésarArquero: it's just two point layers, with a common (UID) field, trivial to mock up.

Comment: the problem stil present in 3.10 and master > 3.12 :/

Comment: and the problem is more generic, e.g. hot to refer a input modeler input or third layer in an generic expression. parameter('...') does not work

Answer (score 3):

I found a possible workaround:

Seems that high level variables (e.g. input model parameters) can't be resolved inside nested expressions.

The trick is to do evaluation at higher level with some kind of lambda (e.g. string concatenation) then refer concatenation result in nested expressions.

I didn't investigate if the reason is that model scope is not propagated or not checked during expression evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

The idea would be to create the join and then create the field:

1. Create geometry from WKT on LAYER2 using `Geometry by expression`
2. Extract the start point of LAYER2 using `Extract specific vertices` and specify first vertex (index 0).
3. Join using `Join attributes by location` using the output of previous alg and of LAYER1.
4. Use the `Field Calculator` using the joined field

Comment: This can easily hit the same referencing problem at #1.

Comment: If you know the field name you can use it directly in the expression since it is joined. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I think I just got confused, you've switched OP's layer 1 and 2.