# QGIS defining beginning and the end of the linear element based on point location from the different layer

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have the situation, where I draw the lines from one point to another. They in fact proceed along with the other linear items, but it works well with the snapping tool.

[image]

As you can see I must fill up the from and to columns, where, from is the one end of my line finishing at the point with ID 34499 and another end (to) is the point with ID 64974.
Is there any way to do it automatically in the attribute table?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in 3 steps:

1. Create a new **WKT** field in the Points layer

> geom_to_wkt( $geometry)

2. Update the **from** field in the line layer with the following formula
   (assuming your points layer is called 'Points' and the  name/ID field is called 'NAME'):

> ```
> to_string( attribute(get_feature('Points','WKT', geom_to_wkt(start_point($geometry))),'NAME') )
> ```

3. Update the **to** field in the line layer with the following formula

> ```
> to_string( attribute(get_feature('Points','WKT', geom_to_wkt(end_point($geometry))),'NAME') )
> ```

As stated this is assuming your points layer is called 'Points' and the  name/ID field is called 'NAME'. If this not the case, update those values in the formulas.

Adapted from this answer:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/209368/10661

[image: Steps involved]